# Incomplete response json from inertia js

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am getting incomplete json response. I dont know what is causing this issue. Here is sample json[image]

I have debug the code Response.php from inertia-laravel

```
   if ($request->header('X-Inertia')) {
        return new JsonResponse($page, 200, [
            'Vary' => 'Accept',
            'X-Inertia' => 'true',
        ]);
    }
```

which seem right and dump & die giving me correct data.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging vendor's packages is always the last check to do.
In your screenshot, the JSON response of the `127.0.0.1` request seems correct, can you show the response on the `log?format` request, where, I suppose, is the error?

Have you try to debug with [Vue Devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/)?